# Regex is matching % and ignoring spaces when I didn't expect it to

Tags: c#, regex

For `token = "A%"` or `token = "A B"`

```
Regex.IsMatch(token, @"[a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z_]|\d)*");
```

is returning true.  Why is it not returning false like I think it should?

Comment: Why don't you use `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z_]`... much cleaner. And which is this language?

Comment: Looks like c#, not all regex specifications have all of the easy escape-macros. Tho the builtin c# one does afaik...

Comment: @Al.G. Except that it's not equivalent in .NET. [`\w`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#PositiveGroup): "A word character is a member of any of the Unicode categories listed in the following table. [...] If ECMAScript-compliant behavior is specified, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`." In the OP's case, ECMAScript-compliant behaviour is not specified.

Comment: @hvd yes, you're right, I forgot that `\w` matched digits.

Comment: @Al.G. I misread, I thought you meant that `\w` was equivalent to `[a-zA-Z_]|\d`. My point was that it's not, except in specific circumstances that don't apply here, because of the many Unicode characters that are also included.

Comment: Thank's all for the edits. It's clearer and has fewer wild assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we break down your regular expression into two parts, we get `[a-zA-Z_]` followed by `(?:[a-zA-Z_]|\d)*`. Now the first part matches only a single character, which is `A` in both of your examples. The second part is followed by `*` which means *repeated zero or more times*.

In both cases, this regular expression will match the first part as `A` followed by the second part repeated **zero** times i.e. nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your expression matches the first A in both:

You are asking for a mandatory `[a-zA-Z_]` followed by an optional part `(...)*`. The mandatory part matches the A while the optional part skipped.

If I understand your intention correctly, then you'd want the regex to make sure there's nothing else in the token. You can do that by adding ^ and $ to the expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z_](?:[a-zA-Z_]|\d)*$
```

or even:

```
^[a-zA-Z_]\w*$
```

Which is equivalent but shorter.